# How to increase precision by hundreds of decimal in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision

I need to compute the intrinsic carrier concentration at very low temperature, which takes very small values (down to 10<sup>-678</sup>) that are rounded to 0 by Python. What do you advise me to do in order to increase precision?

Comment: Why don't you upload the code you've written so far? The question would be a lot better with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Work in logarithmic notation. So instead of storing `x` directly you store `log10(x)`. So in this case you would store `-678`. This keeps multiplication an option, but addition becomes impossible.
2. Use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), and set the precision to a desired level.

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec = 10000
>>> Decimal(10)**-678
Decimal('1E-678')
```

Comment: Is there an intrinsic limit in Python to the precision that you can achieve (perhaps between 32 and 64 bit versions of Python?), or is this limited by the OS - or perhaps there is no such limitation at all?

Comment: @BramVanroy On my machine `decimal.MAX_PREC` is `999999999999999999`, so that's a lot of digits of precision :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! unfortunately I have tried what you suggested and I still get 0 


In [50]: from decimal import Decimal, getcontext


In [51]: getcontext().prec = 10000


In [52]: Decimal(10**-678)

Out[52]: Decimal('0')

Comment: @Sarah You probably messed up. Make sure to directly load the data into a `Decimal` and not first load it as a `float`.

Comment: @Sarah Yeah, you messed up. Look at the difference between what you executed and what I executed. You first have to make sure you're working in 'decimal land' before doing any operations. You first perform `10**-678` in 'float land', and then convert to `Decimal` - but it's too load, it's already rounded.

Comment: Oh yep, I have just spotted my error, I have written Decimal(10**-678) instead of Decimal(10)**-678, thanks !

Comment: @orlp Is there a way to use the Decimal type by default instead of float ? Because I need to convert all the float to Decimal when performing multiplications and it takes some time..

Comment: @Sarah No there isn't.